# How to remove duplicate custom taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use custom taxonomy in my custom post. Suppose I have 12 custom post in 3 categories. I only need to display each category for one time. I have used the following code. But it repeated the categories.

```
<?php
   $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'Categori' );
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo $term->name;
   }
?>
```

Please tell me how can I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_unique()](http://pk1.php.net/function.array-unique) function to remove duplicate values.

But first you need to store your term values in array.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
   $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'Categori' );

   $c_terms = array();         //Create empty array

   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       $c_terms[] = $term->name;
   }

   $unique_cat = array_unique($c_terms);

   foreach ($unique_cat as $cat) {
       echo $cat;
   }
?>
```